# SQL: Select distinct "categories" with at least one row with a certain value

Tags: sql, sqlite, distinct

I have a simple table like this:

```
+----------+----------+
| Category | Favorite |
+----------+----------+
| One      |    True  |
| One      | False    |
| Two      | False    |
| Three    | True     |
| Four     | False    |
+----------+----------+
```

I want to select every category, but each category only once, which has at least one row with `Favorite = True`

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM table_name;
```

This query only gives back every category, not only those with at least one favorite.

I'm not really good at SQL and I don't really know what to exactly search for, which is why I didn't find anything about this. Any help would be really appreciated!

**Edit:**

The output should look like this:

```
+----------+
| Category |
+----------+
| One      |
| Three    |
+----------+
```

Comment: I'm using SQLite for Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below should work as well (MSSQL server):

> if Favourite column is varchar:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category 
FROM table_name
WHERE Favourite = 'True'
```

> if Favourite column is bit:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category 
FROM table_name
WHERE Favourite = 1
```

Comment: This is the closest to what you were trying, I'd say this is the best answer!

Comment: the simplest one

Comment: Yeah that worked, thank you! Didn't know it would be that easy. I had to change "where Favorite = 'True'" to "where Favorite = 1" though, because of SQLite.

Comment: yeah, depend how data is stored, for varchar would be 'True', for bit would be 1/0

Answer (score 2):

Simple grouping should do the trick:

```
Select category from the_table 
where favorite = 1
group by category
```